# Looking for a Way to Reset the `Math` Function

Tags: javascript, math, timer

I'm trying to make a game for my kids that relies on a counter.  I have the counter working fine, except on the third play-throughthe counter doubles in speed.

The first two plays the counter increments 1 second at a time, then the third round it increments two seconds at a time, then the fourth round it increments four seconds at a time, and so on...

My code:

```
timeLeft = {
    total: gameTime,
    mins: function(){
        return Math.floor(timeLeft.total/60);
    },
    secs: function(){
        tempSecs=timeLeft.total-(60*timeLeft.mins());
        if (tempSecs < 10) {
            tempSecs='0'+tempSecs;
        }
        return tempSecs;
    }
};

function timer(){
    $('#time').html(timeLeft.mins() + " : " + timeLeft.secs());
    timeLeft.total=timeLeft.total-1;
    if (timeLeft.total>=0) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            timer()}, 1000);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: The problem is definitely not with the `Math` object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your timeout to a variable: `var myTimeout = setTimeout...` and when you reset the game, run a `clearTimeout(myTimeout);`

Comment: worked like a charm!  thanks!  do you know why the timer function would start to degrade after a couple games?

Comment: It isn't degrading, it's stacking. You were instantiating a new timer on top of the old one every time you ran `timer()`, doubling up the logic, effectively :)

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense.  Thanks for the explanation and solution!